# how to fetch javascript contents in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a website that has data I want to fetch stored in a javascript. How do I fetch it?

The code is this :- http://pastebin.com/zhdWT5HM

I want to fetch from "var playersData" line. I want to fetch this thing :- "playerId":"showsPlayer" (without quotes obviously). How do I do so?

I've tried beautiful soup. My current script looks like this

```
q = requests.get('websitelink')
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)

searching = soup.findAll('script',{'type':'text/javascript'})
for playerIdin searching:
  x = playerId.find_all('var playersData', limit=1)
  print x
```

I'm getting [] as my output. I can't seem to figure out my problem here.
Please help out guys and gals :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` would only help locating the desired `script` tag. Then, you would have multiple options: you can extract the desired data with a javascript parser, like [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit), or use regular expressions:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<script type="text/javascript">
            var logged = true;
            var video_id = 59374;
            var item_type = 'official';

            var debug = false;
            var baseUrl = 'http://www.example.com';
            var base_url = 'http://www.example.com/';
            var assetsBaseUrl = 'http://www.example.com/assets';
            var apiBaseUrl = 'http://www.example.com/common';
            var playersData = [{"playerId":"showsPlayer","userId":true,"solution":"flash","playlist":[{"itemId":"5090","itemAK":"Movie"}]];
</script><script type="text/javascript" >
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

pattern = re.compile(r'"playerId":"(.*?)"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

print pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
```

Prints:

```
showsPlayer
```