# fetch same elements but different values from javascript using python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

This is similar to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892945/how-to-fetch-javascript-contents-in-python).

The thing is that the whole script looks like this :-http://pastebin.com/1MyGGD9h

And as you can see the 'userId' elements are repeated. The python script fetches the first one and ignores the second result. How do I fetch both of them and use their values separately.?

What I think could be done is fetch one element at a time and use the values separately. But, I can't seem to get it work.

Right now, for fetching the script .. my code looks like this:-

```
Import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<script type="text/javascript">
            var logged = true;
            var video_id = 59374;
            var item_type = 'official';

            var debug = false;
            var baseUrl = 'http://www.example.com';
            var base_url = 'http://www.example.com/';
            var assetsBaseUrl = 'http://www.example.com/assets';
            var apiBaseUrl = 'http://www.example.com/common';
            var playersData = [{"playerId":"showsPlayer","userId":true,"solution":"flash","playlist":[{"itemId":"5090","itemAK":"Movie"}]];
</script><script type="text/javascript" >
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

pattern = re.compile(r'"userId":"(.*?)"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

print pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
```

Right now, it shows "true". But, I want both the values. That is.. TRUE and FALSE, form both the elements. Any idea.?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `userid` in your question example but if there were two you should use `findall`, search will stop when it gets the  first match:

```
a,b = pattern.findall(script.text)
```

Your regex also seems incorrect, there are no double quotes areound the values:

```
html="""<script type="text/javascript">
        var logged = true;
        var video_id = 59374;
        var item_type = 'official';

        var debug = false;
        var baseUrl = 'http://www.example.com';
        var base_url = 'http://www.example.com/';
        var assetsBaseUrl = 'http://www.example.com/assets';
        var apiBaseUrl = 'http://www.example.com/common';
        var playersData =     [{"playerId":"showsPlayer","userId":true,"solution":"flash","userId":false    ,"playlist":[{"itemId":"5090","itemAK":"Movie"}]];
</script><script type="text/javascript" >"""


pattern = re.compile(r'"userId":(.*?),')


print pattern.findall(page)
['true', 'false']
```