# Search a string in javascript using python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Following my previous question :
[how to fetch javascript contents in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892945/how-to-fetch-javascript-contents-in-python)

I tried to make another script which fetches the data from a javascript. After getting the webpage contents of course.

But, it's just not showing up the content I want. I want to find "content_id" from the javascript of the page. This is the page :- http://www.hulu.com/watch/815743

Here's what I have right now.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import fileinput


Link = 'http://www.hulu.com/watch/815743'
q = requests.get(Link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)
#print soup
subtitles = soup.findAll('script',{'type':'text/javascript'})
pattern = re.compile(r'"content_id":"(.*?)"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
print pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
```

I get this error :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Any idea how to solve this issue..?

Comment: Have you considered searching for *"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute"*? There are quite a few similar questions out there already...

Comment: I tried the solutions ... didn't work.

Comment: I literally do not believe you - and even if you actually *had* tried all of the various suggestions, why don't you mention that *in the question*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your regular expression pattern:

- the *quotes are escaped with backslashes* in the script contents, take that into account
- there is a *whitespace after the colon*

Here is the fixed version:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\\"content_id\\":\s*\\"(.*?)\\"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

Works for me, getting `60585710` as a result.

FYI, here is the complete code that I'm executing:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Link = 'http://www.hulu.com/watch/815743'
q = requests.get(Link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)

pattern = re.compile(r'\\"content_id\\":\s*\\"(.*?)\\"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
print pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
```

Comment: Okay. I see the error... But, I'm still getting the same error. Did you change anything else in your script?

Comment: It seems that my python installation had some error.I tried my code on other machine and it worked. Thanx :)